# Limitation of generic types

Tags: delphi, generics

This declaration with generic types will not compile

```
type
  TFoo<T> = record
    Value : T;
  end;

  TFooo = TFoo<TFoo<Int64>>; // this is fine
  TFoooooInt64 = TFoo<TFoo<TFoo<Int64>>>; // E2564
```

because of

> E2564 Undefined Type '`TFoo<T>`'

This error E2564 is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2564_Undefined_type_%27%25s%27_%28Delphi%29) as

> This occurs when trying to define a type restraint on a generic type using itself.
>
> ```
> program E2564;
>  
> {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
> type
>   TRec<T: record> = record
>     A: T;
>   end;
>  
>   TClass = record
>     V: TRec<TClass>; //E2564
>   end;
>
> begin
> end.
> ```

But this it not the case here.

Is this a bug or is this limitation documented?

Comment: It's not documented, and is it a bug? Only Emba can answer that.

Comment: Yes, I think so and now I am waiting on https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12138 for that well known **works as designed** *(but not documented)* reply :o)